# How do lower case letters works in QR code?

Tags: character, qr-code, lowercase

I have a little doubt about QR character list. A summary of the specification is here:

```
Numeric only    Max. 7,089 characters (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
Alphanumeric    Max. 4,296 characters (0–9, A–Z [upper-case only], space, $, %, *, +, -, ., /, :)
Binary/byte     Max. 2,953 characters (8-bit bytes) (23624 bits)
Kanji/Kana  Max. 1,817 characters
```

How does it works for the characters out side these lists, like lower case letters or ~,? etc.?
As for example : The QR code for    **a~?bC** generated from [here](https://www.the-qrcode-generator.com/):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE9d6.png)

How does it work? Because few characters *~ ? a b* are not listed in the standard QR code character list.

Comment: The `Binary/byte` format allows you to use standard ISO/IEC 8859-1 character codes, according to the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Storage).

Comment: @KenY-N Thank you for your answer. Can you please explain it how does it work?

Comment: The `Binary/byte` format is just treated as a normal string of text (by default I would presume), and if the QR Code app finds the text starts with `http://` it assumes it is a string.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that they would just occupy more data/blocks per character and increase qr size to higher level, becoming less space efficient.

Answer (score 0):

For text encoding, two characters only use 11 bits, saving on space.

But when needed, you can always use the binary format to store any custom characters you want. For example you could use ascii or Utf-8.